# How to Mark final result as PASS if one of the Test Suite in Robot Framework Passes?

Tags: robotframework

We have a scenario where we need to run the same test suite on 2 different Geo Redundant servers to check the health. If any one of them passes the final Report & Log should show the suite as pass.

Is there a way in the robot framework to achieve this?

For example, lets say I have following robot file:

> Health_Check_Server.robot

```
*** Test Cases ***
Validate Server
   [Arguments]   ${Server_credentials}

   Login to Server    ${Server_credentials}
   ${HC_Output}=      Run Command        ${health_check command}
   $HC_Status}=       Validate Output    ${HC_Output}
```

I want to execute it like:

```
robot --variable Server_credentials:<ServerA details> Health_Check_Server.robot
robot --variable Server_credentials:<ServerB details> Health_Check_Server.robot
```

Is there any option in the rebot command using which I can OR the results?
Meaning if any of these Servers are in healthy state, the final results should show PASS. Only if both of the suites failed, the final result should be marked as FAIL.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just save each result in separate file, and than merge the result using [rebot](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-rebot).
The log will have the test inside as passed, you should see a note if one of the tests was failed.

```
robot --variable Server_credentials:<ServerA details> --output server_a.xml Health_Check_Server.robot
robot --variable Server_credentials:<ServerB details> --output server_b.xml Health_Check_Server.robot
rebot --merge server_a.xml server_b.xml
```

Comment: Well, the problem with that approach is that you really need to know the order. If server_A failed and server_B passed, I will get a pass on the final result. However, if its vice versa, it will mark the final result as failed. Basically it assumes that the last XML in the command was the latest result and it gets precedence. What I need here is regardless of the order in which they were executed, the result should be OR'ed. Is there any option in rebot (or anywhere else in the robot framework) for that?

Comment: you are right only the latest is taken in the account. You could use option **--rerunfailed** when running the test for the second time, however the second test will only run when the first is failed :-(. Then you can safely say that the server is running. You can also use the return codes of the test runs to combine the results to your needs. This solution is not that elegant but should do the trick

Comment: So there is a way to pass a different variable value with --rerunfailed option? Because in this case I will have to specify server_B details for resun if the server A check failed.

Comment: yes that is possible, you can create 2 variable files and pass these to your commands, something like:
 
first command
 **robot --variablefile variables_b.py --output b.xml  test.robot** 
second command
  **robot --variablefile variables_a.py --rerunfailed b.xml --output a.xml  test.robot**

Comment: This would not work in my case, because I have multiple test cases even though in the example, I showed only one. Requirement is that the whole test suite should PASS for at least one of the servers. In this scenario, the 2nd robot command will only execute the failed test cases from 1st run and update the results accordingly. This is more of a retry for failed test cases, not for the whole test suite.